# RoR link to specific controller in routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I use Ruby 2.0 and Rails 4.2.0. I can't create link for simple_form_for in _form.html.erb. My code:
routes.eb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    namespace :admin, path: 'uceadmin' do
        root :to => 'dashboard#index'
        namespace :newsletter, path: 'newsletter' do
          resources :lists, controller: 'newsletter_lists' do
            resources :subscribers, controller: 'newsletter_subscribers'
          end
        end
    end
end
```

app\views\admin\newsletter_subscribers_form.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
  <%= simple_form_for([:admin, :newsletter, @list, @newsletter_subscriber]) do |f| %>
```

rake routes:

[image]

And what I have in result:

```
undefined method `admin_newsletter_newsletter_list_newsletter_subscribers_path' for #<#<Class:0xd1d5af0>:0xdc2a7b8>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should use the :url option to pass URL for submitting. In your case it is admin_newsletter_list_subscribers_path, as I can see.

```
<%= simple_form_for @newsletter_subscriber, url: admin_newsletter_list_subscribers_path(@list) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Just not correct name of the controller. My fail =\